# Combo Box, in datagrid view, selection not retained c#

Tags: c#, datagridviewcombobox

I have `datagridview` which has three columns in which two columns are simple non- editable text columns.Third one is a combo box column.If I change a value from dropdown of combo box and click another cell, value is reset to default.Selection changed is not retained.

Which event should I handle the selection change?
How do I retain the value in combo box selection?

I am attaching data source in the below mentioned

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn checkType = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)grdCheck.Columns[(int)CheckColumn.CheckType];
CheckType.DisplayMember = "Name";
CheckType.ValueMember = "Name";

CheckType.DataSource = CheckTypes();
```

whereas CheckTypes() contains

```
CheckTypes()
{
   var CheckTypes = new[] 
   { 
      new { Name = "None", Id = "1" },
      new { Name = "View", Id = "2" },
      new { Name = "Edit", Id = "3" }
   };

  return CheckTypes;
}
```

I have not added events here as I have a save button which saves the selection directly from datagridview to database.

Comment: Where is the code that applies the `DataSource`? You're not doing that on selection change are you?

Comment: I am doing CheckType.DataSource = CheckTypes(); during form initialization.Yes you right.I am not doing that on selection change.Should I add it also during selection change? Thanks for immediate help :)

Comment: No, definitely not. Your value should stick, there must be something about some code you haven't shown.

Comment: Exactly,I am not getting how to make the modified selection retain.I am assuming that it will happen here itself (CheckType.DataSource = CheckTypes();) This is the total code I have.

Comment: I am not sure which event will be called during selection change of combobox in datagridview.

Comment: I doubt you are even concerned with the selection changed event. If you have properly data bound your data to the grid then change tracking will be handled. [On my blog](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/05/27/c-data-binding-example-with-adapters-and-datagridview/) I have a link to a project that demonstrates databinding with a grid and combobox columns. It might help you to look it over.

Comment: Thank you for sharing you blog,I am checking your project.I was just assuming some missing links has to be provided, may be during an event, so the thoughts :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your project, It helped me in understanding binding combo box of data grid view with underlying database.